# Running Onnx file from Mendix studio pro

Tags: onnx, onnxruntime, mendix

I want to understand how can I use ONNX model in mendix studio pro , I checked all the documentation from mendix and tried implementing it in mendix studio pro, but I'm not able to figure out how can I pass any inputs to roberta_base_11 ONNX model in microflow to get the sentiment of my text.

I have imported the Sentiment Analysis ONNX model in mendix studio pro it created two entities like this:

[image: Entities from Onnx file]

I called it from microflow passing 4543 as input_id to my ONNX model then it gave output object with attributes

```
output_1:"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'
output_2:"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"
```

I just want someone to explain me what kind of input send to this ONNX model,I don't have any ml knowledge so I am not able to figure out how can I use this ONNX model.
so that I can send my own text to get the sentiment of the text.